# Getting the change number of the first revision of a file in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, changelist

Is there a way to retrieve the change of the first revision of a file in Perforce? Sometimes I want to read the job description of the change that introduced a file, in order to learn what the file does, as well as to find related CRs for more information. I'm looking for something in the command line, *e.g.*

```
p4 <something> <file>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, never mind, I found the subcommand I needed, `p4 fstat`, just after posting the question.

```
$ p4 fstat cama_Preempt#1
... depotFile //depot/MMA/products/CAMA/main/src/testScripts/cama_Preempt
... clientFile /ext1/acheong/CAMA/main/src/testScripts/cama_Preempt
... isMapped
... headAction add
... headType text
... headTime 1174070670
... headRev 1
... headChange 168703
... headModTime 1174070479
... haveRev 1
```

The `headChange` field shows the change number.